# Finding the sum of a series $\frac{1}{1 \cdot 2}-\frac{1}{2 \cdot 3}+\frac{1}{3 \cdot 4}-\frac{1}{4 \cdot 5}+....$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

The value of:

$$ \frac{1}{1 \cdot 2} - \frac{1}{2 \cdot 3} + \frac{1}{3 \cdot 4} - \frac{1}{4 \cdot 5} + \cdots $$

is

> ```
> (A) between 0 and 1/4.
>
> (B) between 1/4 and 1/3.
>
> (C) between 1/3 and 1/2.
>
> (D) between 1/2 and 1.
> ```

I was looking for a convenient way to tackle it. Can someone point me in the right direction? Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Which problem would you like someone to solve?

Comment: sorry for the wrong post.I have edited it.

Comment: Isn't it time for you to have learned TeX, rather than posting images?

Comment: Does the above really mean $1.2=\frac{12}{10}$ or does it mean $1\times 2$?

Comment: $\log(x)$ expansion and then integrate

Comment: It means $1\times 2$

Comment: Admitedly, the question is not a very good one, and it would be nice to see more effort by the OP, but closing as "not constructive" seems a bit harsh. Does it really qualify as "As it currently stands, this question is not a good fit for our Q&A format. We expect answers to be supported by facts, references, or specific expertise, but this question will likely solicit debate, arguments, polling, or extended discussion."

Comment: @ThomasAndrews: the lower dot format is common in Europe to mean multiplication.

Comment: Yeah, I was aware of that, and that was my firs interpretation, just wanted to make sure which format was in use. @rlgordonma

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an alternating series with monotonely (ignoring the signs) decreasing terms. The proof of Leibniz' test shows that the value of the series $s$ lies between two consecutive partial sums.

Hence
$$\frac{1}{2} > s > \frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{6} = \frac{1}{3}.$$

Answer (score 1):

It's same as $(1-\frac{1}{2})-(\frac{1}{2}-\frac{1}{3})+(\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4})-(\frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{5})+\cdots=1+2(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\frac{1}{4}+\frac{1}{5}-\cdots)$

$=1+2(\ln2-1)=2\ln2-1\approx 0.3862$